# Java - Stack Datastructure implementation using array

Tags: java, data-structures

I'm trying to implement push and pop operations using stack.

Below is the code

```
public class StackMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        StackDS obj = new StackDS();
        obj.push(10);
        obj.push(20);
        obj.push(30);
        obj.push(40);
        obj.push(50);

        System.out.println("Before pop");
        obj.print();
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("After pop");
        obj.pop();
        obj.print();
    }

}
```

Here, my original array size is 5. After inserting 5 elements, the `top = 5.` So, I'm trying to `pre-decrement the top variable` to retrieve the value using pop operation.
So when I do the pop operation using `arr[--top]`, it is actually fetching the `4 element (40 in this case)`. But, actually it should fetch the `5th element (50).` I'm not sure, what i'm doing wrong here. 
please find the eclipse debugger result.

[image]

Comment: You appear to be decrementing `top` twice, each time you `pop`

Comment: @StephenC - After changing to arr[top] = 0; it is working fine. Thanks.

Comment: `--top` will update the value of `top` as well! Either use `top-1` to get a "side-effect free" evaluation or use `--top` once and afterwards `top`.